# Vim: copy a pattern from one file and search it in the other

Tags: vim, replace

Suppose we've opened two files A and B in `vsplit` mode. Now there is a pattern `p` in A, and one wants to yank it (switch visual mode and `yy`) and search for it (via typing `/` in command mode) in B. How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>"</kbd> to paste the contents of the default register into a `/` search or a `:` command. If you've done the yank using `yy` then the text will be in the default register so this will be what you want.

If the text you want has been yanked into a register other than the default then just use the register letter or number in place of the <kbd>"</kbd> e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd> to paste the contents of register z.

Search down [the command line documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html) for `CTRL-R` for some more details and special registers that can be used.